# "Something went wrong. Please try again later." when creating Data Source after installing SSRS 2019 and restoring ReportServer DBs

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, portal

I've installed the latest version of SSRS 2019 and restored ReportServer + ReportServerTempDB from a development server. It has custom security setup (we just use our own cookie for access), but all works fine until I try to create an SSRS Data Source. As soon as I click the "+ New" > "Data Source" drop down, I'm presented with "Something went wrong. Please try again later." as below.

[image: SSRS Error Message Web Portal]

The installation is the same as on all other servers it's been installed on.

I've noticed in the console that this is the source of the error msg:

https://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Extensions?$filter=ExtensionType+eq+(cast(%27Data%27,%20%27Model.ExtensionType%27))

... or even this:

https://localhost/Reports/api/v2.0/Extensions

... and the response to both of these is:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"0","message":""
  }
}
```

"https://servername/Reports/api/v2.0/Extensions" returns a valid response on the other server, as reference:

```
{
"@odata.context":"https://(devservername)/Reports/api/v2.0/$metadata#Extensions","value":[
    {
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"SQL","LocalizedName":"Microsoft SQL Server","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"SQLAZURE","LocalizedName":"Microsoft Azure SQL Database","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"OLEDB-MD","LocalizedName":"Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"SHAREPOINTLIST","LocalizedName":"Microsoft SharePoint List","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"ESSBASE","LocalizedName":"Oracle Essbase","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"SAPBW","LocalizedName":"SAP BW","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"OLEDB","LocalizedName":"OLE DB","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"ODBC","LocalizedName":"ODBC","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"XML","LocalizedName":"XML","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Data","Name":"ENTERDATA","LocalizedName":"Enter Data","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "@odata.type":"#Model.DeliveryExtension","ExtensionType":"Delivery","Name":"Report Server FileShare","LocalizedName":"Windows File Share","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ],"IsImmutable":false,"DefaultDeliveryExtension":false
    },{
      "@odata.type":"#Model.DeliveryExtension","ExtensionType":"Delivery","Name":"NULL","LocalizedName":"Null Delivery Provider","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ],"IsImmutable":false,"DefaultDeliveryExtension":false
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"RPL","LocalizedName":"RPL Renderer","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"HTML5","LocalizedName":"HTML5","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"HTML4.0","LocalizedName":"HTML 4.0","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"RGDI","LocalizedName":"Remote GDI+ file","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"NULL","LocalizedName":"NullRenderer","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"ATOM","LocalizedName":"Data Feed","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"XML","LocalizedName":"XML file with report data","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"CSV","LocalizedName":"CSV (comma delimited)","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"MHTML","LocalizedName":"MHTML (web archive)","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"IMAGE","LocalizedName":"TIFF file","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"PDF","LocalizedName":"PDF","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"PPTX","LocalizedName":"PowerPoint","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"EXCEL","LocalizedName":"Excel 2003","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"EXCELOPENXML","LocalizedName":"Excel","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"WORD","LocalizedName":"Word 2003","Visible":false,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "ExtensionType":"Render","Name":"WORDOPENXML","LocalizedName":"Word","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ]
    },{
      "@odata.type":"#Model.DeliveryExtension","ExtensionType":"DeliveryUI","Name":"Report Server FileShare","LocalizedName":"Windows File Share","Visible":true,"Parameters":[
        
      ],"IsImmutable":false,"DefaultDeliveryExtension":false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Take a look and see if there is extended exception info in the ReportingServicesService_* for the ssrs api. The SSRS Manager also has an extended log :  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles--> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/reporting-services-log-files-and-sources?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Frustratingly, the log file was 0 bytes but was fixed as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem, by using my machine name and also "localhost" in both the Web Service URL and Web Portal URL. It may be that internal reporting services were confused because I'm also using localhost with a different port in Visual Studio, but stopping IIS express didn't resolve the issue. I added a self signed cert. for my machine name, and I'm using only that. It also gets confused if using a self signed cert. for localhost and the machine name. It's a shame it can't be hosted in IIS, because there's lots of issues with self-hosting SSRS.

Nothing was logged in RSPortal_*.log - it was a 0 byte file until this was updated.

The next issue was finally logged in RSPortal_*.log after the above fix (The report server was unable to validate the integrity of encrypted data in the database.). It was caused by viewing existing data sources and fixed by hitting the "Change" button in encryption keys